# Re-flex library not found in C++ autotools project

Tags: c++, macos, compiler-errors, include, autotools

I am working on a compiler project so I am using Re-flex for the lexer and Bison for the parser.

The build project is based on autotools and everything is fine except one thing :

```
fatal error: 'reflex/matcher.h' file not found
#include <reflex/matcher.h>
```

It seems that reflex can't be found. I am on Mac M1 and I have installed re-flex with Homebrew.
I tried a lot of things to solve this problem like export the path of the library with :

```
export CPATH=/opt/homebrew/include
export LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/homebrew/lib
```

Or

```
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/re-flex/include"
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/re-flex/lib"
```

But nothing works. Is there any way to include the path to the library to make my project build correctly ?

Comment: Impossible to answer without knowing what the "autotools-based build system" supports in terms of options. Maybe there is an option for setting the reflex prefix? who knows?

Comment: I understand you to be saying that this is *your* project, from which I conclude that you are in control of the build system.  In that case, it is conventional to make `configure` check for required headers and libraries, especially for third-party software.  It is commonplace to provide a means to tell `configure` where to find particular ones, and for `configure` to prepare your makefiles appropriately.  For header file locations, that normally means adding `-I` options that get included in the `CPPFLAGS` for the targets that need them.  Details depend in part on whether you use Automake.

Comment: Actually the :
`export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/re-flex/include"
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/re-flex/lib"` solved the problem.